# I need an interval scrip or something that would help me solve the thing that i am aiming for

Tags: discord.js

So basically, Im trying to make my bot direct message everyone in my server,but what i want it to do is dm a specified amount of members every specified interval, for example:

the bot dms 5 members every 10 minute.

If you have any idea of a script i could possibly use it would be a thank you, also this is in javascript!

Comment: You need to use the `discord.js` tag instead of `discord`

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: 12.2.0 @Syntle is the version i am using

Comment: Are you trying to DM lets say 5 random members every 10 minutes?

Comment: yes @Syntle thats exactly what im trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`client.setInterval()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=setInterval) to run the following every 10 minutes:

```js
client.setInterval(() => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(GUILD_ID)
    guild.members.cache.random(5).forEach(member => member.send('Hello'))
}, 600000)
```

Comment: Do you have a full script that i can see it in 
@Syntle